# Angular - Filter array based on two property values

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having some problem in deleting the array items based on two property values..

If we compare to classic Sql delete command, What I have to do is something like this:

```
DELETE oImages WHERE idOffertRow = 1 and idProductImage = 2
```

I don't know how to convert this sql example command in typescript.

This is that I'm ttrying to do but it doesn't work:

```
this.oImages = this.oImages.filter(function (obj) {
          return obj.idOffertRow !== oRow.idOffertRow && obj.idProductImage !== i.idProductImage;
        });
```

Thanks to support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.oImages = this.oImages.filter(obj => idOffertRow !== 1 || idProductImage !== 2);
```

Filter is about keeping, not deleting. So invert your condition. With De Morgan's law, it gives

```
A . B ---> !A + !B
```